# Using text to mask a video

Tags: html, css, canvas

Is it possible to use HTML/CSS text to mask a video? I've found and set up ways that sort of work, but none allow for a transparent background behind the text.

For example, this pen requires you to have some sort of fill, where it isn't really masking the actual video, but creating the illusion.

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/QvvEYQ

If you change

```
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

To

```
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

You'll see that it's just a white fill with a mask on the fill, not the video.
Perhaps this is possible only in canvas?

Comment: why don't you use `z-index` property if you just wanted the text to levitate over video

Comment: The goal is to have the video playing on loop with the text hiding parts of the video.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can achieve it with canvas quite easily, using [compositing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) and a rendering loop:

```js
var vid = document.createElement('video');
vid.onerror = function() {
  vid.onerror = null;
  vid.src = "http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4";
};
vid.src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ocean-small.webm"
vid.muted = true;
vid.onloadedmetadata = initCanvas;
vid.loop = true;
vid.play();

function initCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var vWidth = vid.videoWidth;
  var vHeight = vid.videoHeight;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  // we need to handle the resizing of our canvas ourselves...
  window.onresize = function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = (vHeight / vWidth) * canvas.width;
    var fontSize = (vWidth / 2 * (window.innerWidth / vWidth)) * 0.35;
    ctx.font = '700 ' + fontSize + 'px Impact,sans-serif';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  };
  onresize();
  
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  draw();
  
  function draw() {
    // first draw our video frame
    ctx.drawImage(vid, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // set the composite mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';
    // will remove every pixels that are not where new pixels will come
    ctx.fillText('OCEAN', canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    // reset the normal compositing mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    // do it again at next screen refresh
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, blue 100%) no-repeat;
}
```

But that may not be the best solution in term of performances and scalability.

You should be able to apply the same svg `<mask>` you were using on your `<video>` element (with some modifications), but it seems SVG masks over HTML content is still not widely supported (Firefox accepts it, Chrome doesn't...).

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, blue 100%);
}
svg{
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
}
video {
  -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
  mask: url(#mask);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="100%" height="100%">
      <text fill="white" x="0.5" y="0.5" style="font-weight:700" font-size="0.22" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">OCEAN</text>
    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
<video autoplay playsinline muted loop preload poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/oceanshot.jpg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ocean-small.webm" />
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" />
</video>
```

So a better solution might be to use an SVG [`<clipPath>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) which seems to have better browser support than CSS `mask`.

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, blue 100%);
}
svg{
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
}
video {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg style="opacity:0;position:fixed;z-index:-999" viewBox="0 0 1 1">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <text x="0.5" y="0.5" font-size="0.22" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">OCEAN</text>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<video autoplay playsinline muted loop preload poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/oceanshot.jpg">
  <source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/ocean-small.webm" />
  <source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/ocean-small.mp4" />
</video>
```

*Note that I don't really know browser support for css clipPath neither, so you might have to fallback to canvas for some browsers.*