# See through text with video playing

Tags: css

Basically what I have right now, is a gradient background on top of a video and now I'm trying to create a see-through text that allows you to see parts of the video. Can someone help? :)

```css
.fullscreen-bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -100;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gradient-bg{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgb(63,61,106);
    background: linear-gradient(52deg, rgba(63,61,106,1) 0%, rgba(98,0,0,1) 100%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen-bg">
  <video autoplay muted loop class="fullscreen-bg__video">
    <source src="videos/typical-new-york-city-summer-street-market-nyc-walk-thru-2018-june-8-real-sounds-unedited.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="videos/typical-new-york-city-summer-street-market-nyc-walk-thru-2018-june-8-real-sounds-unedited.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
        
<div class="gradient-bg">
  <h1><span>New York Street Food</span></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! You can add `color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)` to span. It will make the text color black and slightly transparent. If you want more/less transparency just change the 4th parameter.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for? https://codepen.io/cypark/pen/vOwPOd

Comment: There are some possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054146/using-text-to-mask-a-video