# i'm trying to mask the text with a video background but it isnt working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

This video shows what i want the result to be: https://youtu.be/n_9UKMDEYg0
when i try to make this animation it doesn't work

i tried using mix-blend-mode and tried using a transparent background.

my goal is to have the background and text the same colors as in the video, then the text becomes transparent revealing the video .

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.video-background {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-background > video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.video-background > img {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;

  /* animation: scale 6s forwards 1s; */
}

.video-background > div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /* opacity: 0%; */
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  animation: fade 3s forwards;
}

.video-background > div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  animation: to-white 3.5s forwards, blend 3.5s forwards, scale 4s forwards 4s;
}

.video-background > span {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* top: -6%;
  left: 0%; */
  font-size: 37vw;
  font-weight: 700;
  user-select: none;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.75rem;

  animation: slide-in 2s forwards 500ms;
  transform: translateY(-150%);
}

@keyframes scale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(250);
    display: none;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  70% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes to-white {
  0% {
    color: #141414;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
  }

  75% {
    color: #141414;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
  }

  76% {
    background-color: #000;
  }

  100% {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }

  70% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}

/*
video-background > span {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "IntervalNextWideBold";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 70vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  animation-name: drop-down;
  animation-duration: 3.6s;
  animation-direction: normal;
  transition: 1s;
  user-select: none;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

@keyframes drop-down {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    color: #fff;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    color: #fff;
  }
  100% {
    
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@keyframes background-fix {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
} 

@keyframes blah-blah {
  0% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='main.css'>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ramabhadra&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="video-background">
        <video src="video.mp4" autoPlay loop muted></video>
        <div></div>
        <!-- <img src="/GPSI-background.svg" alt="background" /> -->
        <span>GPSI</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please make a runnable snippet which shows the problem. And have you looked into any sort of masking?

Comment: This shows some ways of having a video show thro' text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054146/using-text-to-mask-a-video

Comment: @AHaworth what I need is the transition from normal color to a video background

Comment: If you already have a way of showing a video through text then please show us that code. Then it's just a matter of moving a colored nand a video element - is it that movement that you are stuck on rather than the transparency?

Comment: my issue is with the transparency, I have created the start animation and the scale animation, but I couldn't figure out the Transparecy

Comment: Have you tried anything from the link above?

Comment: yes i did, but it didn't give the result i wanted

Comment: That’s surprising as it shows how to make a text shaped ‘hole’ through which a video, or anything else can be seen. Then all you have to do is move them. I don’t think I can help any more than that.